Would a question regarding a specific crypto library be on topic @ crypto.SE?
For example, would a question asking what the Blowfish structure BLOWFISH_CTX or the variables xl and xr do in the following header does be on topic here?
/*
blowfish.h:  Header file for blowfish.c

Copyright (C) 1997 by Paul Kocher

This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
Lesser General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA


See blowfish.c for more information about this file.
*/


typedef struct {
  unsigned long P[16 + 2];
  unsigned long S[4][256];
} BLOWFISH_CTX;

void Blowfish_Init(BLOWFISH_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *key, int keyLen);
void Blowfish_Encrypt(BLOWFISH_CTX *ctx, unsigned long *xl, unsigned long *xr);
void Blowfish_Decrypt(BLOWFISH_CTX *ctx, unsigned long *xl, unsigned long *xr);

Or would that belong at SO or CR.SE?

Please ask programming related on SO. Crypto.SE focuses on the mathematical models behind cryptography.

@HendrikBrummermann That's why I thought that more people at Crypto.SE might know about what xl and xr are supposed to be.

Such a question should be asked on Stack Overflow.
As the help center says:

If your question is about using a cryptographic library (e.g. Crypto++, OpenSSL etc) and using it in your application, you probably need Stack Overflow. (A good indicator is the existence of source code in your question or most good answers).

